# what do we mean by range in descriptive statistics?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, dispersion, range

The definition of the range has been given as the difference between the largest and the smallest value of the distribution. This, in my perception, tells us the discrepancy between the smallest and largest value and does not measure the dispersion from the central value.

So, my question is how does that help us in finding the dispersion of the observation from the central value of the same? In other words, why do we consider range as a measure of dispersion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In statistics, dispersion (also called variability, scatter, or spread) is the extent to which a distribution is stretched or squeezed.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion))

It does not say “from the central value”. Dispersion is about how the data is spread out, obviously, if it has a big range it is very spread out.

Some dispersion statistics like variance or [MAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) measure the spread relative to the central value, but others like range or [IQR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) do not.